# SSRS: Combining multiple reports into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have 3 different reports each using a different dataset and parameters, and I'd like to make one parent report that groups them together in a way that you could switch between them, and only show one at a time (so not all 3 on the same page where you'd have to enter inputs for all 3 even if you only need one).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean, subreports? Yes, they've been in SSRS since at least SSRS 2005. Seems like you just need to implement a parameter and expression to toggle their visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!

Make a new report that will become your main report. Then, in the body of the main report instead of inserting a table or a textbox you can insert a subreport. Insert three subreports and then go into the properties of each to link them to each report you want to include in the main report.

I recommend having the subreport only contain the tables and the main report to have the headers.

Then you set the visibility of the subreport to toggle depending on the parameters, ex:

= IFF(Parameters!Para.Value = "", False, True)

Comment: Hi Kim, after trying this out, SSRS gives me an error message as 'Error: Subreport could not be shown'. Do you have any idea why that is ? Do note that each subreport must receive parameters to display its data, I'm not sure how it would work here if I wanted to pass both the parameter for which report to show and the parameters of the subreport. (if that even is where the error is coming from).

Comment: Hello Nossair, I have encountered that problem and I have found a solution. The problem is: it was two weeks ago and I do not remember what was the specific problem. Do you have any more information on the problem? Here are some steps I took to troubleshoot my subreports: 1. Does the subreport run when you are not in the main report? If yes, that means that its the connection between the main report and the subreport. 2. The main report is supposed to feed its parameters into the subreport.

Comment: Lets say I have an rdl file called subreport1. It has the following parameters: ClientCode that is text, WantDescription that is boolean. Make sure that you are able to preview that subreport without issues. Now lets have a rdl file called mainreport1. Insert a subreport. Go into the properties of that subreport object, choose subreport1. Create ClientCode and WantDescription parameters. Make sure that they are the SAME DATATYPE (text and boolean). Go into the subreport object properties -> parameters. On the left it should be the names of the subreport parameters. On right: main rep values.